# How to view all internal hard drive information if the hard drive is not showing up in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, crash

My computer recently underwent an unrecoverable crash and I installed Windows on my other hard drive to get it running again. Now, I cannot view the original hard drive at all. It is plugged in as before, when it was working, but it does not show up anywhere, even in device manager.

Answer (score 0):

Reboot and enter BIOS. There you will be able to find list of HDD's connected to your pc. If missing disk isn't listed there:

1. Power off your computer,  unplug all SATA\IDE devices except problematic disk
2. Connect HDD to a different SATA\IDE, also try replacing a cable

check BIOS once more. If problem remains - your HDD is dead

Comment: If it was dead, would it still spin? I'll try this, although I think last time it wasn't listed. The hard drive still spins and vibrates, even though it's undetected by the computer (again, I'll check the BIOS again to make sure it's not just Windows).

Comment: Yes, it will. Mechanical part is ok, so it starts to spin when pc is powered on, but some of microchips are dead, so no communication occurs between pc and hdd

Comment: Could a faulty power supply do this, too? My power supply has been notorious for occasionally being very loud and annoying.

Comment: Yes, it could. Check power lines voltages in bios, run some tests.

Comment: Alright. It showed up in BIOS and now shows up in Windows, when it didn't before. When I first plugged it in (I had unplugged it), it made some scratchy, uncomfortable sounds, now it's pretty smooth. The CPU Vcore Voltage is +1.176V, CPU IO Voltage is +1.056V/+1.064V (alternating), DRAM Voltage is +1.504V, GPU Voltage is +0.24, 3.3v is 3.328V/+3.344V (alternating), and 12v is +11.968V

Comment: Did you switch sata\ide port and cable for this hdd? 

btw, is your hdd sata or ide?

Comment: Since it showed up this time, I didn't switch the cable or port. I didn't think it was the port considering it works this time. It's a SATA HD (Seagate Barracuda LP ST31000520AS).